# axios get request to localhost:4000/ gives responseUrl of localhost/ resulting in 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am adding a server extension to an existing same-server backend:

```
import server from 'myserver';
import { verifyJwt } from 'jwt.middleware';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = server.getApp();

app.use(function (ctx, next) {
  ctx.cacheControl = {
  noCache: true
 };
  return next();
});

const client = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    Pragma: 'no-cache',
    Expires: '0'
  }
});

const router = server
  .getRouter({ prefix: '/myuserendpoint' })
  .use(verifyJwt);

router.get('/goodusers', async ctx => {
     const result  = axios.get('/api/users');    
    // do something with result
 ctx.body= result;
});
```

I run the server and try to access `http://localhost:4000/myuserendpoint/goodusers` which is going through,but when I expect axios to call `http://localhost:4000/api/users` (a working endpoint), it gives me 404 error and in the error message I find a call to a wrong address of `http://localhost/api/users` instead (where is the port number?).

I need to extend the functionality of an existing same-server endpoint to do some changes in the result and send it back via a new route. We have `/users` endpoint and I want to have `/goodusers` which uses the existing `/users` API and filter some of them with a logic.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should not make an HTTP call to an end-point on the same server. You can just define a function that handles the logic.

Comment: @lpizzinidev But I need to extend the functionality of an existing same-server endpoint to do some changes in the result and send it back via a new route.
let say we have `/users` endpoint and I want to have `/goodusers` which uses the existing `/users` API and filter some of them with a logic.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
const instance = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000'})

instance.get('/widgets')
.then((response) => {res.json(response)})
.catch((error) => {res.json(error)})
```

Comment: Have you read the question at the first place? This is a total random answer!